# How would you improve this object model design to get around Covariance Issues with ObjectModel.Collection<T>?

Tags: c#, collections, generics, inheritance

Consider the following simple relationship.

[image: Class Diagram]

**Code**

```
[DataContract(Name = "Wheel")]
public class Wheel { }

[DataContract(Name = "OffRoadWheel")]
public class OffRoadWheel : Wheel { }

[DataContract(Name = "RoadVehicle")]
public class RoadVehicle
{
    public Collection<Wheel> Wheels { get; private set; }

    public RoadVehicle()
    {
        Wheels = new Collection<Wheel>();
    }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Truck")]
public class Truck : RoadVehicle
{
    public Collection<OffRoadWheel> OffRoadWheels { get; private set; }

    public Truck()
    {
        OffRoadWheels = new Collection<OffRoadWheel>();
    }
}
```

The Collections are configured as Read-Only and initiated in the class constructor as per FXCop recommendation CAS2227. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327(VS.80).aspx

Now I know all the rules about Covariance & Contravariance, and the varying capabilities of using Collections vs. Lists vs. Enumerables (vs. their Interface Equivalents). However the above object model creates a number of competing difficulties.

If you create a truck with 4 Off-Road Wheels, down cast it to a RoadVehicle, and then iterate the Wheels collection... it's empty.

One way around this would be to create a `public new Collection<Wheel> Wheels` property on the `Truck` class which on-the-fly casts the contents of the `OffRoadWheel` collection, but this breaks behaviour if you go to add or remove on that collection.

Another problem is serialization, you can alter the above to store and duplicate the inner `Wheels` and `OffRoadWheels` properties, but then you'd end up complete serializing both if you wanted to serialize `Truck`

Any other suggestions on how to make this more Developer Friendly object model where things happen as you'd expect them to?

Comment: I'm a little concerned about having classes to represent off road wheels and wheels.  Other than attributes (tread pattern, size, width, max speed, etc.) are there any differences between the two?  I think the design is flawed.

Comment: it's a hacked together example to represent a real-world solution.

Comment: or do you think that kind of "Square Relationship" is inherently flawed in any system.

Comment: I think you could have just a Wheel class that has an attribute type (Off-Road, Touring, Racing, Slick, ...) in it.  This will save you a bunch of extra classes, and the type could be an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the model here is broken. If you have a `RoadVehicle` that's actually `Truck`, the interface lets you to add a normal `Wheel` to it, which is wrong.

One way to make it work is to make the collection immutable (e.g. `IEnumerable<T>`). This can be a reasonable solution if you're okay with setting the wheels only in the constructor.

Comment: Alternatively rather than via the constructor you could have an AddWheel(Wheel wheel) method and the Truck could be responsible for knowing what wheels it supports?  I guess this then could potentially lead to a builder pattern? i.e. AddWheel().AddDoors() ....

Comment: @dreza I think that still breaks LSP. If you have a method `AddWheel(Wheel)`, then it shouldn't accept only a specific type of wheel.

Comment: Wouldn't constructors get a bit crowded if this were the case.  What would be another alternative to constructor injection?

Answer (score -1):

Create constructors that take appropriate wheel collections. then `RoadVehicle` constructor looks like this `public RoadVehicle(Collection<OffRoadWheel> hotWheels) : base(hotWheels) {}`

Comment: That creates bi-directional coupling. The base types shouldn't know about the child types. e.g. what if the child types were defined in a seperate assembly, you'd end up with a cyclic reference to achieve what you're trying.